# Assigning row number according to the Column value SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this in SQL server 2014:

```
name    
a       
a       
b       
b       
b       
c       
d       
d       
d
```

I want to create another column that is S.No. , but serial number value will be assigned according to name column. If name occurs 2 times the value of s.no. will be 1 and 2.If d is 3 times than value for d will be 1,2 and 3 and than again counter will start with 1 for e. so the table will be like:

```
name    S.no.
a       1
a       2
b       1
b       2
b       3
c       1
d       1
d       2
d       3
```

Any solution? thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) [S.no.]
FROM T
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in another way by using `Count()`

```
select 
Name,
Count(1) over (partition by Name ORDER BY Name ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as Slno
from MyTable
```